# contentOverlayView on TVOS not showing

Tags: objective-c, video, tvos, apple-tv

```
myview = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc]init];
[window.rootViewController.view addSubview:controller.view];

UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
label.text = @"TEST";
label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Menlo" size:(72.0)];
[myview.contentOverlayView addSubview:label];

myview.view.frame = window.rootViewController.view.frame;

// Disable playback controls
myview.showsPlaybackControls=false;

// show the view controller
[window.rootViewController addChildViewController:myview];
```

myview is playing video, but the "TEST" label isn't visible. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Anyone found a solution to this?